# This expression is not constructable.Type 'typeof import("../node_modules/spotify-web-api-js/src/typings/spotify-web-api") has no construct signatures

Tags: ionic-framework, constructor, ionic2, spotify

This expression is not constructable.
Type 'typeof import("c:/Users/Acer/Downloads/ionicspotify4/node_modules/spotify-web-api-js/src/typings/spotify-web-api")' has no construct signatures

Here is the code:

```
import * as SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-js';

export class HomePage {
result = {};
data = '';
playlists = [];
spotifyApi: any;
loggedIn = false;
loading: Loading;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage, private plt: Platform, 
private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
this.spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

this.plt.ready().then(() => {
  this.storage.get('logged_in').then(res => {
    if (res) {
      this.authWithSpotify(true);
    }
  });
});
```

}

I am trying to load playlist of spotify using spotify api but this is giving me the error mentioned above
I have tried to install it using 'npm i spotify-web-api-js' but that wont work and this still gives the same error

Same error exists in my PlaylistPage

Here is the code:

```
import * as SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-js';
@IonicPage()


@Component({
  selector: 'app-playlist',
  templateUrl: './playlist.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./playlist.page.scss'],
})


export class PlaylistPage implements OnInit{
  tracks = [];
  playlistInfo = null;
  playing = false;
  spotifyApi: any;
  currentTrack: MediaObject = null;
 loading: Loading;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private media: 
Media, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    let playlist = this.navParams.get('playlist');
    this.spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

    this.loadPlaylistData(playlist);
  }
```

Comment: I'm stuck on this too, any solutions?